# Substitute for Selenium.browserbot.getActiveWindow().$ in WebDriver

Tags: jquery, webdriver, selenium-rc

Currently i am using

```
String jQuery = Selenium.browserbot.getActiveWindow().$
```

to get jQuery handle in Selenium RC script

Now i am migrating my script to WebDriver.

What will be the substitute for String jQuery = Selenium.browserbot.getActiveWindow().$ in webdriver?

NOTE -- I tried running the script in Webdriver with String jQuery = $ But it returned me null when i execute the javascript which runs perfectly with Selenium RC using String jQuery = Selenium.browserbot.getActiveWindow().$

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver exposes a function called getWindowHandle to get current window's handle.
You can use this as driver.getWindowHandle

java.lang.String getWindowHandle() :
Return an opaque handle to this window that uniquely identifies it within this driver instance. This can be used to switch to this window at a later date

Reference this : http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

Also, I think you need to add a return statement to your javascript in webdriver, which wasn't the case with Selenium.